# I need to see if two numbers are multiples

Tags: c++, division, multiplication

I need to see if two numbers are multiples, and in case they are provide a positive answer, or in case they are't provide a negative one. However, everytime i try to make the prog there are always errors, i'm not sure i'm doing it right.

```
    int A;
int B;
float C;

printf("enter two numbers\n\n");
scanf("%d %d", &A, &B);

C=A/B;
D=A/B;

if (A/B=C) printf ("no");
else printf ("yes");
```

Comment: "there are always errors" Can you be more specific?   It might be helpful if you provide minimal, *compileable* code.

Comment: What kind of errors? If that is your real code then you have to declare a main function. `int main() { ... }`. You also need to include the header for printf and scanf `#include <stdio.h>`. Perhaps you just need to read a book?

Comment: i have the int main and the include, it says "ivalue required as left operrand of assignement"..

Comment: That error is because `if (A/B=C)` should be `if (A/B==C)`

Comment: thanks, now it works, but it says 2 and 8 are not multiples

Comment: Back up; start by saying, in words, what it means for one number to be a multiple of another. Then think about how to write the code.

Comment: Why not use modulus operator. It will be easier.

if A>B and A%B = 0 then they are multiples.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious error in your code is

```
if (A/B=C)
    // ^ you are using assignment (=) here, not comparison (==)
```

try

```
if (A/B==C)
```

Answer (score 0):

With A,B > 0; A and B are multiple if `A % B == 0` or `B % A == 0`
(% is the modulo operator)

so

```
bool isMultiple(unsigned int A, unsigned int B)
{
    if (A == 0 || B == 0) {
        return A == B;
    }
    // A != 0 && B != 0
    return (A % B == 0) || (B % A == 0);
}
```